# p7zip API design

Tags: 7zip, api-design

Is there any reason why `maxCheckStartPosition` is designed to be a pointer here?

This variable is used as a search limit and I don't see any reason why it would get changed during Open().

And also I grepped the whole library and I cannot see any `Archive` takes the ownership / changes that variable.

This design decision really looks strange to me.

```
p7zip_9.20.1/CPP/7zip/Archive/IArchive.h:

STDMETHOD(Open)(IInStream *stream, const UInt64 *maxCheckStartPosition, IArchiveOpenCallback *openArchiveCallback) x; \
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't see any reason why it would get changed during Open().

Beyond not seeing any reason why, contractually it would be undefined behavior if it did.  It's labeled `const` *(and written like that, it's the thing pointed to that's const... not the pointer)*.

> Is there any reason why maxCheckStartPosition is designed to be a pointer here?

Without knowing the specific motivations:

- Being a pointer allows for NULL, to be optional while still having the full range of a UInt64 available if non-NULL.  This prevents needing to pick a "magic number" meaning no maxCheckStartPosition.
- On a 32-bit architecture, a pointer would mean 32-bits in the passed parameter on the stack vs. 64-bits...for which there could be better-or-worse reasons.  Some might be trying to micro-optimize the bytes pushed, other times perhaps it may be another weird reason why something you're interfacing with only knows how to push pointer-sized-things to the stack (an FFI-like thing, or something).

Comment: Thanks. The NULL checking makes sense to me.